# Remove index.php from url Laravel 5

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, laravel-5, laravel-routing

URLs are working fine in my application. I mean they are pretty URLs. Like **http://www.example.com/**
But it also works when you access the page with **index.php** like **http://www.example.com/index.php**, which I don't want because it is showing two links in sitemap for one page. One page without **index.php** and another with **index.php**. Demonstration of the sitemap is here https://www.xml-sitemaps.com/details-eln.6762418.html

Here is the **.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Dropping the one you don't want from the sitemap seems like the easiest solution.

Comment: right. bt i want to fix it on the application side.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put the following code :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,7}\s/(.*)index\.php\sHTTP.*$
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: when i implemented the above code the issue with index.php is resolved but all the links are broken. any idea?

Comment: its in the root directory.

Comment: On local machine if i run http://localhost/myproject/index.php, it takes me back to http://localhost/xampp/. Is it right? I mean it should take me back to http://localhost/myproject. what do u say?

Comment: its not working for other links. can u please paste full code for .htaccess file in ur answer.

Comment: What about NGinx?