# Remove index.php from routes in Lumen/Laravel

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel, ubuntu, lumen

I move my Lumen Project to Ubuntu.

I cant access to defined routes without `index.php`.

I can access to routes in this way:

```
public/index.php/api/user
```

I tried the command `a2enmod rewrite` and restart apache2 but this not work for me. I do not know if is the file .htaccess in the public file.

Any help?

Comment: You possibly need the Apache "AllowOverride All" directive in the root directory or virtual host directory to allow the .htaccess file to work correctly

Comment: I put AllowOverride All but dont works, appears Domains Errors.

Comment: Have you defined document root in apache config? Please share your apache configuration

Answer (score 2):

move .htaccess and index.php on folder public to root folder your project
open index.php and then rename

$app = require **DIR**.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
to
$app = require **DIR**.'/bootstrap/app.php';

Note, while copy pasting underscore sign is not being copied.

Answer (score 1):

Put this in .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index [NC]    
RewriteRule ^ / [R=302,L,NE]
```

see this   [how-to-remove-public-from-url-in-laravel](https://hellocoding.wordpress.com/2014/05/17/how-to-remove-public-from-url-in-laravel/)
and this [Remove index.php from url Laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32358942/remove-index-php-from-url-laravel-5)